# Cocos2d How to use CCC4?

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone

Any one have any ideas on how to convert ccc3 to ccc4 or even just a macro!
I am currently using CCMotion streak and it requires me to use ccc4 but i dont know what combination makes what color!
Please any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from ccTypes.h

```
typedef struct _ccColor4B
{
 GLubyte r;
 GLubyte g;
 GLubyte b;
 GLubyte a;
} ccColor4B;
//! helper macro that creates an ccColor4B type
static inline ccColor4B
ccc4(const GLubyte r, const GLubyte g, const GLubyte b, const GLubyte o)
{
 ccColor4B c = {r, g, b, o};
 return c;
}
```

For exampe:

`ccColor4b myColor = ccc4(255, 0, 0, 255);` creates a solid red color

Again from ccTypes.h

```
/** Returns a ccColor4F from a ccColor3B. Alpha will be 1.
 @since v0.99.1
 */
static inline ccColor4F ccc4FFromccc3B(ccColor3B c)
{ 
 return (ccColor4F){c.r/255.f, c.g/255.f, c.b/255.f, 1.f};
}
```

If it's not enough for your write your own converter like the last one

**EDIT:**

If you have `ccColor3B myColor3B` and you want to have `ccColor4F myColor4F` simply use the converter:

```
myColor4F c = ccc4FFromccc3B(myColor3B);
```

If you want to have ccColor4B write your own converter:

```
static inline ccColor4B ccc4BFromccc3B(ccColor3B c)
{ 
 return (ccColor4F){c.r, c.g, c.b, 255};
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ccColor4B c = ccc4BFromccc3B(myColor);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the the post! Do you think you could explain on how to use the code you have posted? Thanks

Comment: Okay im extremely sorry but I stil dont get it. Just to explain once more basically i am using CCMotionStreak and it requires me to use ccc4 and i want to convert my ccc3 color to ccc4. If possible could you please make a project and post the code online? Just a tip I tried doing this:                                       CCMotionStreak *streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:2 minSeg:0 image:@"Stars.png" width:32 length:32 color:ccc4FFromccc3B(255,0,0)]; but it gave 3 errors! Thanks once again.

Comment: there is an example coming with cocos2D (it's called motionStreakTest). Your code does not work because you need ccColor4B and you are trying to put ccColor4F

Comment: Thanks for informing me about that, but do you know how to convert ccColor4B to ccc3? Thanks

Comment: It's just to structures - write your own converter. If it's hard for your - think about learning c before writing some complex applications

Comment: please could you tell me where i need to put the static inline part?

Comment: If you want to use it only in a single .m (.mm) file you can put there. If you want to use it in many .m files then put in some header witch you will import in your .m file. You can also put it in ccTypes.h

Comment: I added the code for the converter and then `ccColor4b myColor = ccc4(255, 0, 0, 255);
` but I get xcode wanting to convert ccColor4b to glColor4ub!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue with CocosSharp (the Xamarin C# port of Cocos2D):

To convert a CCColor3B to a CCColor4F, you can pass in the CCColor3B as a argument to the constructor of CCColor4F.  For example:

```
var color = new CCColor4F (CCColor3B.Red);
```

CCColor4B doesn't have a constructor with CCColor3B as an argument, so you have to pass in the individual values for Red, Green, and Blue, as follows:

```
var sourceColor = CCColor3B.Red;    
var color = new CCColor4B (sourceColor.R. sourceColor.G, sourceColor.B);
```

I like to create extension methods to encapsulate the above, as follows:

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static CCColor4F ToColor4F(this CCColor3B sourceColor)
    {
        return new CCColor4F (sourceColor);
    }

    public static CCColor4B ToColor4B(this CCColor3B sourceColor)
    {
        return new CCColor4B (sourceColor.R, sourceColor.G, sourceColor.B);
    }
}
```

So you can then perform conversions using the following:

```
var bColor = CCColor3B.ToColor4B();
var fColor = CCColor3B.ToColor4F();
```